# How can I make all rows of matrix sum 1 from tensor in pytorch

Tags: matrix, pytorch

I have a matrix, which is from Cora.

The size of it is [2708,1433]

For any rows, the elements are 1 or 0. I want to make "sum of elements of any rows be 1, by dividing sum of rows."

How can I make it? At first I thought I can do it by 'for' and 'append' command.

Is there any easier way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
xs = xs / xs.sum(dim=-1).unsqueeze(-1)
```

If `xs` is your Tensor, `xs.sum(dim=-1)` is the summation over the column-index (i.e. a Tensor of shape (2708,). By unsqueezing it, you turn it into a matrix of shape (2708, 1) which you can then [broadcast](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/broadcasting.html) against `xs`. The result of the division
is a matrix, all rows of which sum to 1:

```py
xs.sum(dim=1)
assert torch.allclose(torch.ones(xs.shape[0], dtype=float), xs.sum(dim=1))
```

ps: if `xs` is ones and zeros, you might need to cast it to `float` first:

```py
xs = xs.to(float)
```

Comment: Your code well acted, but how can I make ```xs.sum(dim=-1) ==1``` all True?? It gives me a result all False

Comment: extremely small numerical differences will fail the strict equation check -- the correct way to go about it is to use `torch.allclose(...)` instead

Comment: Can you be specific? Actutally I did ```assert (xs.sum(dim=-1) == 1).sum() == xs.size(0)``` and it made an assertion error...

Comment: Why are you plugging in the equation check?  `xs.sum(dim=-1).sum() == xs.size(0)` is what you should be checking. Your snippet tries to assert that the sum of the entire matrix is 1, not that each row sums to 1.

Comment: otherwise: just print `xs.sum(dim=-1)` and convince yourself that you get a vector of ones

Comment: Actually, I am using PytorchGeometric, and I want to apply WLConv with Cora data. ```assert (xs.sum(dim=-1) == 1).sum() == xs.size(0)``` is the SourceCode of WLConv, and it gives me AssertionError...


To check, xs.sum(dim=-1) == 1).sum() was 2240. I want to make it 2708 because xs.size(0) ==2708.  So I think the small error is the problem....

Comment: If you think the mistake is with the module, you can fix it and make a pull request on the official repo. Or, could it be the case that the normalization it asserts is what you really need to do? Because this is not what I understood of your original formulation in the question